# Unable to find .env file in Go file executed via serverless function

Tags: go, environment-variables

I have a React web app calling a Go 'backend' (i.e. serverless functions) - but for whatever reason it can't access my .env file.

My overall project structure is roughly as follows:

```
- root
-- .env
-- src
-- api (where my functions are stored)
```

As a result, I figured I'd just be able to utilise a dotenv package. However, my file is returning the first err, indicating it can't find the variable.

```
package handler

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func Main(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No .env file found")
        log.Panicln("No .env file found")
    }

    uri := os.Getenv("MONGO_URI")

    fmt.Println(uri)

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why my app can't find my .env file, despite it existing?

Comment: The binary you build from your `main` package is entirely separate from the module source. None of the files exist at that point, you need to deploy any extra files with whatever deployment system you are using, and locate them relative to the executable working directory or via complete paths.

Comment: Yeah think you're right, it's pulling it now after pushing again.